# Connecting to external oracle database using db_set_active in settings.php not working

Tags: 7, configuration, database

In DRUPAL7 i am trying to connect to oracle external db using `db_set_active('ora_db')`. here is my code snippet in settings.php. i am not sure where i am going wrong.
when i try `oci_connect('uname','pass','db_name/service_name')` it works fine in my drupal page. but when i try using drupal way to connect oracle db it's not working.

Note: just for database connect i don't want to use other modules

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'db_name1',
      'username' => 'xxxx',
      'password' => 'xxxx',
      'host' => 'host1',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'mportal' =>
  array(
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'db_name2',
      'username' => 'zzzzz',
      'password' => 'zzzzz',
      'host' => 'host2',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
'ora_db' =>
    array(
    'default' =>
        array (
        'database' => 'ora_dbname',
                'username' => 'yyyyyy',
                'password' => 'yyyyyy',
                'host' => 'ora_db_host_name/service_name',
                'port' => '1521',
                'driver' => 'oracle',
                'prefix' => '',
            ),
    ),
);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal core doesn't have an Oracle driver, so you can't use the API with an Oracle database unless you install a module (or find another way to introduce the code, but it would be counter-intuitive not to use a module).

The [Oracle Driver](https://www.drupal.org/project/oracle) module provides what you need, if you don't want to install it you're stuck using `oci_connect` etc.

Comment: call me crazy but PDO supports ODBC as well -- isn't there an Oracle ODBC driver one could install on the server?

Comment: there is no specific documentation on how to use Oracle Driver module. 
i installed the module and no configuration appears, am i missing something here?

Comment: @vnimbala The configuration page is at admin/config/development/oracle. For the rest, it's a database driver; you just tell Drupal the kind of database engine to use, in the settings.php file.